# upload image to firebase from ckeditor4 using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am working on one Blogging application where I want to upload image to any database or specifically firebase from ckeditor4 using angular application.
I have gone through documentation where I am able to upload image to ckeditor from my file browser. But I don't see have any clue how to upload it to my database.

Below is my code.

**component.html**

```
 <ckeditor [config]="config" data="<p>Some initial data</p>" type="classic" formControlName="body"></ckeditor>
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
this.config = {
      extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
      uploadUrl: 'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',

      // Configure your file manager integration. This example uses CKFinder 3 for PHP.
      filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.html',
      filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
      filebrowserUploadUrl: 'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
    }
}

// how do I inovoke below function on file upload from ckeeditor
uploadToFirebase(){
 // code to upload image to firebase
}
```

Is there a way I can make work this thing in angular application with any other editor where I want to upload image from my file browser to database while writing blog.

Comment: Any updates on this? Is it possible to upload to a Firebase storage?